# Conditional Mapping of POCO entities using Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent, fluent-interface

I have this POCO class :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyKey { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool DiscriminatorField { get; set; }
    public string AnotherInfo { get; set; }
}
```

My database model is as such :

- Main

  - ID int
  - Name varchar
  - DiscriminatorField bit
- Specific1

  - ID int
  - AnotherField varchar
- Specific2

  - ID int
  - AnotherField varchar

**The question:** Using fluent API (and most likely `EntityTypeConfiguration`), how can I create this conditional mapping where `AnotherField` of my entity gets filled by `Specific1` if the discriminator is `true`, and by `Specific2` if the discriminator is `false`?

Note: I do not want to create two different POCOs. I'm looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6672767/68693), but conditional.

Edit: Added the discriminator field to the POCO entity.

Comment: In order to condition to be checked, you have to get the value of discriminator from the database. At that point, entity framework will already expect that you have provided it with entity model definition - which you can't since you want conditional mapping. I don't see how you can manage to do that but I might be mistaken.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my post and add the discriminator field to my entity. Does it make it possible?