# (Not A Duplicate) How to fully map a single class to 2 tables based on their parent class in Entity Framework, I'm not asking about class splitting

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Say I have the following classes:

```
class Tag
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

class EntityA
{
    //ctor, other properties, etc
    public List<Tag> Tags {get; set;}
}

class EntityB
{
    //ctor, other properties, etc
    public List<Tag> Tags {get; set;}
}
```

Is there a way in `EF` to map my lone Tag class to 2 unrelated tables (`EntityATag` and `EntityBTag`) as well as their linking tables (`EntityA_EntityATag`)? For query performance reasons I want to have 2 separate `Tag` tables, but am hoping I can keep working with just one `Tag` class instead of a class per table.

Thanks!

**UPDATE: This is NOT the same question as [mapping multiple tables to a single entity class in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670580/mapping-multiple-tables-to-a-single-entity-class-in-entity-framework)**.
That question is about **splitting** a single class into multiple tables. I don't want to **split** my Tag class, I want to map the full class to two different tables depending on which entity I'm working with (`EntityA` or `EntityB`)

Comment: Correct, not a duplicate. What you want is called polymorphic associations.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to have your `Tag` be an interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more about the EF implementation. Having had a similar problem some time ago I found that [this reference](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) hit the spot.

You could implement `tag` as an abstract class.